# Changing : with pipe(|)

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a lot of text files that I need to append the name of the file at the end. I have just DOS commands available. I managed to append the name at the beginning using:

```
findstr "^" *.txt >new.dat.
```

Unfortunately I cannot append to the end using `findstr "$" *.txt new1.dat`. 
I cannot understand why the `$` (which should be [line position : end of line') is not working.

The second thing I'm trying to replace `:` (colon character) inside the file with the `|` (pipe). I use the script:

```
@echo off setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion  
for /f "tokens=* delims= : %%a in (new1.dat) do ( echo "%%a| >>new2.dat ).
```

The file looks like this:

```
batch-2016-03-14-08-50-05.txt:6530635|GB|150316|6530635.png
batch-2016-03-14-08-50-08.txt:6530636|GB|150316|6530636.png
```

I just want to replace the `:` with the pipe (`|`)

Comment: To append to the end of a text file, just echo 'blah' >> textfile.txt

Comment: Try this  http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.FindAndReplace

Comment: "Lines containing characters among "&<>]|^ may be treated incorrectly."

Comment: I thought `for /f` and `findstr` didn't exist in DOS, but only on Windows?